# Piping results from ls -l in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, awk, ls

So I used:

```
getent passwd $2 | awk -F: '{print "|Username: " $1 "\n|Password: " $2 "\n|Uid: " $3 "\n|Gid: " $4 "\n|Comment: " $5 "\n|Home: " $6 "\n|Shell: " $7 "\n"}'
```

to pipe user info in to a neat list.

I wanted to do the same with folders. I want all the information from the ' ls -l'  command but instead of it coming out like a block of test I wanted it listed piece by piece.

Can I use an `awk` command together with `ls` and can I use the same method I did earlier?

Comment: Not *reliably*, because the fields in the `ls -l` output are not unambiguously delimited like those in the `passwd` database. See for example [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead)

Comment: @Fredrik, add `groups | sed 's/ /, /g;s/^/Groups: /'`  at the last line of your script.

Answer (score 5):

Since you are on Linux you should instead look into the `stat` command with a proper format (`-c`, `--format`). Little known feature, the format accepts C-style length specifiers, so try for instance:

```
stat -c 'File: %-40n Size: %6s Flags: %8A' *
```

You can put arbitrary strings in the format, and you can even put linefeeds in it (using the `$'string'` syntax):

```
stat -c $'--------------\nFile:     %n\nSize:     %s\nFlags:    %A' /boot/*
--------------
File:     /boot/abi-4.13.0-45-generic
Size:     1501528
Flags:    -rw-r--r--
--------------
File:     /boot/config-4.13.0-45-generic
Size:     213220
Flags:    -rw-r--r--
--------------
File:     /boot/config-4.15.0-72-generic
Size:     217468
Flags:    -rw-r--r--
--------------
File:     /boot/config-4.15.0-74-generic
Size:     217503
Flags:    -rw-r--r--
--------------
File:     /boot/config-4.15.0-76-generic
Size:     217503
Flags:    -rw-r--r--
```

Comment: I personally like that, but the assignment specifically wants it to look like this: https://gyazo.com/3187d434117170d01771760c5f2770f8

Comment: See augmented answer

Comment: The problem with stat over ls -l is that I also want to see the owner of the file, size, and dates.

Comment: See the the format descriptions for stat, it's all there AFAIK.